# How to pull relevant data from Excel table, create dropdown and build edit form in PowerApps?

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-selected-items

This question is extension of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63984559/how-to-use-button-to-display-filtered-data-from-excel-table-in-powerapps/64022315#64022315), where basically, On button click user will know which systems are available. Next, I would like to build a form where User can signup for a system. For this I would only like to pull the systems that are "Available". In this case, it will be "Sys1" and "Sys2". For this I created a button on my Main screen, which will navigate to the signup form.

In the signup form (Screen2), I used Forms -> Edit forms to create my form. Next I would to create dropdown for my "System" dropdown. So, end-user can select "Sys1" or"Sys2". My question is how should I pull the instruments that are available and create dropdown for my System column?

If there is reference available for this task feel free to attach link with your response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the other post, you already got the idea/syntax to [filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-filter-lookup#examples) the datasource and get the required items list to display in gallery. So you have two screens, first screen to show them the availability of items, then in the second screen when they navigate for signup, just wanted to show a dropdown to choose one of the the available items to register. This is redundant, because they can choose one in first screen and directly confirm/fill other data in second screen.

Still if you want flexibility for users to change the item in second screen, dropdown is fine. You have to insert a dropdown control and set the properties/formula. Whatever it is, either a list, gallery or dropdown - the Items property should be filled by our filtered list. [Read more](https://sachinbansal.blog/2018/05/23/common-data-service-for-apps-canvas-app-filter-records-based-on-criteria-part-4/)

[image]

Then on selection and submission - we have to store in database on second screen submit button click using `Patch` function or `SubmitForm`. [Read more](https://sharepains.com/2020/06/19/patch-vs-submitform-vs-update-power-apps/)